# Return back the correct staff_ids

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is that the results are returning back with the same `staff_id` for each grouped record.

However occurring to the database data this wouldn't be the case, could someone help me with whats going wrong with my `query`?

Direct_message table:

[image]

Direct_message_group table:

[image]

Direct_message_thread table:

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT direct_message.id,
       direct_message_group.staff_id,
       direct_message.subject,
       direct_message.creator_id
FROM
  (SELECT direct_message.id,
          direct_message_group.staff_id,
          direct_message.subject,
          direct_message.creator_id
   FROM direct_message
   INNER JOIN direct_message_thread ON direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id
   LEFT JOIN direct_message_group ON direct_message_group.chat_id = direct_message.id
   WHERE ( direct_message.creator_id = '10896'
          OR direct_message_group.staff_id = '10896' )
     AND direct_message.school_id = '1'
   ORDER BY direct_message_thread.inserted DESC) direct_message,
     direct_message_group
GROUP BY direct_message.id
LIMIT 0,
      25
```

Returned data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => direct_message Object
        (
            [id] => 65
            [staff_id] => 7237
            [subject] => TESTING
            [creator_id] => 10896
        )

    [1] => direct_message Object
        (
            [id] => 66
            [staff_id] => 7237
            [subject] => 
            [creator_id] => 10896
        )

    [2] => direct_message Object
        (
            [id] => 67
            [staff_id] => 7237
            [subject] => 
            [creator_id] => 10896
        )

    [3] => direct_message Object
        (
            [id] => 68
            [staff_id] => 7237
            [subject] => 
            [creator_id] => 10896
        )

)
```

What i'm using this data for:

[image]

Comment: first run this query then check result

SELECT direct_message.id,
          direct_message_group.staff_id,
          direct_message.subject,
          direct_message.creator_id
   FROM direct_message
   INNER JOIN direct_message_thread ON direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id
   LEFT JOIN direct_message_group ON direct_message_group.chat_id = direct_message.id
   WHERE ( direct_message.creator_id = '10896'
          OR direct_message_group.staff_id = '10896' )
     AND direct_message.school_id = '1'
   ORDER BY direct_message_thread.inserted DESC

Comment: That doesn't look valid to me, you're only grouping by 1 of the columns and ,there's no condition on your join between  direct_message, &    direct_message_group;

Comment: @JeffUK I've added image of what i'm using this data for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the searching round and testing, i've worked it out.

Query:

```
SELECT direct_message.id, direct_message.subject, direct_message.creator_id, direct_message_group.staff_id, (
    SELECT max(inserted)
    FROM direct_message_thread 
    WHERE direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id
    ) as inserted_order
FROM direct_message
LEFT JOIN direct_message_group ON direct_message_group.chat_id = direct_message.id
WHERE
( direct_message.creator_id = '10896' OR direct_message_group.staff_id = '10896')
AND direct_message.school_id
GROUP BY direct_message.id
ORDER BY inserted_order DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no condition on your implicit join between `direct_message`, and `direct_message_group`.  So you're seeing the results of a Cartesian join. (in other words, every group is joined to every message; if you remove the 'limit' you'll see more clearly what's happening)

You should join them explicitly using a `JOIN` statement and apply an `ON` condition.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example query based around my query?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, so not really!

Comment: I'm trying to get any group message or single chat message which belongs to the selected `staff_id` and `school_id` from above i'm using staff_id: `10896` and school_id: `1` then I want to group it by chat id but want to list them in order of newest chats which have a new message sent to them.

Comment: Hope you understand what i'm trying to achieve with my previous message?